# TCP port scanner written in Python using Scapy yields no response

Tags: python, python-2.7, tcp, scapy, port-scanning

I’m trying to make a TCP port scanner, but I’m sticking to a very simple example that I lined together from a more advanced example I found online.

I don’t get any errors.

I’m expecting the code to show me that port 80 is open since I started my Apache server on my Linux box.

**Here is the code:**

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import logging
logging.getLogger("scapy.runtime").setLevel(logging.ERROR)
from scapy.all import *

ip = "127.0.0.1"
port = 80

response = sr1(IP(dst=ip)/TCP(dport=port, flags="S"),verbose=False, timeout=0.2)

if response :
    if response[TCP].flags == 18 :    
        print "Port open"
```

**Warning I had** (but that does not show up any more):

> WARNING: No route found for IPv6 destination :: (no default route?)

I read that including these two lines below would help on the error:

```
import logging
logging.getLogger("scapy.runtime").setLevel(logging.ERROR)
```

**Nmap scan:**

```
STATE SERVICE
80/tcp   open  http
```

**The output is…** Nothing at all.

I tried several things like changing the port to different other ports, some which I had open and some which I did not.

Any ideas as to what I did wrong?

Comment: `logging.getLogger("scapy.runtime").setLevel(logging.ERROR)` doesn’t prevent the problem; it just says “don’t tell me there’s a problem (even though there is)”.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [scapy docs](http://www.secdev.org/projects/scapy/doc/troubleshooting.html#i-can-t-ping-127-0-0-1-scapy-does-not-work-with-127-0-0-1-or-on-the-loopback-interface) mention that the loopback address is a special case

> The loopback interface is a very special interface. Packets going
>   through it are not really assembled and dissassembled. The kernel
>   routes the packet to its destination while it is still stored an
>   internal structure. What you see with tcpdump -i lo is only a fake to
>   make you think everything is normal. The kernel is not aware of what
>   Scapy is doing behind his back, so what you see on the loopback
>   interface is also a fake. Except this one did not come from a local
>   structure. Thus the kernel will never receive it.
>
> In order to speak to local applications, you need to build your
>   packets one layer upper, using a PF_INET/SOCK_RAW socket instead of a
>   PF_PACKET/SOCK_RAW (or its equivalent on other systems that Linux):
>
> ```
> >>> conf.L3socket
> <class __main__.L3PacketSocket at 0xb7bdf5fc>
> >>> conf.L3socket=L3RawSocket
> >>> sr1(IP(dst="127.0.0.1")/ICMP())
> <IP  version=4L ihl=5L tos=0x0 len=28 id=40953 flags= frag=0L ttl=64 proto=ICMP chksum=0xdce5 src=127.0.0.1 dst=127.0.0.1 options=''
> ```
>
> |\>

However testing this on my OS-X machine results in the following error:

```
>>> conf.L3socket=L3RawSocket
>>> sr1(IP(dst="127.0.0.1")/ICMP())
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scapy/sendrecv.py", line 334, in sr1
    s=conf.L3socket(filter=filter, nofilter=nofilter, iface=iface)
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scapy/supersocket.py", line 64, in __init__
    self.ins = socket.socket(socket.AF_PACKET, socket.SOCK_RAW, socket.htons(type))
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'AF_PACKET'
```

So your mileage may vary

**EDIT**

Apparently this is a known bug in scapy on BSD like systems (including OS-X): http://bb.secdev.org/scapy/issue/174/sniffing-loopback-in-mac-os-x-darwin